# MySql select all from two tables result in a lot of duplicates

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, express, duplicates

I'm using mysql db from oracle (latest version 8.*).
I'm using node js with express. I have several tables with the exact same layout.
All using an auto_increment id and some columns.
For the index page. I need the fetch all data from multiple tables.
I have the following tables: beers (100 rows), non_alcoholic_beers(7 rows) and red_wines(50 rows).

Accordingly to the Oracle documentation a simple:
SELECT * FROM table1, table2; or
SELECT * FROM table1 join table2;
should suffice.
It's works kinda....

But if I do this I get 52+K records. A lot of duplicates thus. I only expect 157 records.

A simple: 'SELECT * FROM table1;' works perfectly.

Can anyone show some light on this matter? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Also, Please stop using comma based Implicit joins and use [Explicit `Join` based syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44917/explicit-vs-implicit-sql-joins)

Comment: Some sample data with expected output will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your tables are not related to each other (no foreign key) and you just want to get all the results combined you should use `UNION`.
It merges the result of queries . You can try it like

```
Select * from table1 
UNION 
Select * from table2
```

Comment: Union requires both select queries to have same no of columns. This query will fail if both the tables dont have same no of columns

Comment: He said he has multiple tables with exact same layout